# Referrencing local fonts

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts

Typically, I see people do something like this:

```
 font-family: -apple-system, ...., Tahoma, ..., or whatever other system font
```

Now, if we include a font from Google Fonts or elsewhere we get a big

```
 @font-face {
      font-family: name;
      src: url() or local(NameWeight-Type), local(Name Weight Type), ......
      font-style: style corresponding to "-Type"
      font-weight: weight corresponding to named Weight of font
}
```

inclusion with all the ones selected via the platform for embedding or get embedding by request from the platform itself.

With local fonts is this still necessary? Meaning, if I do:

```
 font-family: local font 1, local font 2, ....;
```

as listed above in a stereotypical "system font stack" with a bunch of font weights, styles, etc. across the site do I still need to define explicitly or is the browser just leveraging `font-synthesis` to make these?

I don't see how it references the proper files without this. Moreover, how is `system-ui`, `system`, `ui-sans-serif`, `ui-serif`, .... deterministic in this manner?

Comment: `system-ui` just asks the "system" what font is being used by the "ui" and fills in that font. Similar behavior for the `ui-` prefixed generic font names. So, that's as deterministic as the system OS is.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes I'm aware of this.... I was asking more along the lines of RobertAKARobins answer. Deterministic in the sense of font variant mappings rather than what (generic) font family gets filled - as there is clearly always a deterministic system font to fill.

But, given this, I guess it makes sense the browser can also handle the mappings to the proper fonts and styles as they're referenced in further styles.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a local font, then it is not necessary to include the additional weights/styles as long as they are attached normally to the base font. If other applications can figure out how to make the font bold/italic/whatever, then your browser will be able to as well.

Note that this applies only for local fonts. Your browser needs the extra specification for fonts hosted remotely because your computer's font system won't be able to "help" it.

Comment: Makes sense. Digging deeper.... Let's take a system font like this: `/usr/share/fonts/wenquanyi/wqy-zenhei/wqy-zenhei.ttc: WenQuanYi Zen Hei Mono,文泉驛等寬正黑,文泉驿等宽正黑:style=Regular` on Arch Linux. The second is clearly a local variant (in terms of language) so is it proper to do `local(english name)`, `local(other name)`, ....? This seems to me to risk buggy behavior if the system in question doesn't have the proper font mappings. I can certainly easily envision systems where only the local name is referenced rather than full i18n mappings in the font system....

Comment: That sounds risky to me too. There are very few situations in which using local fonts on a public website is a good idea since you have no guarantee of what fonts the end-user has, nor whether they're set up correctly. If you want to be absolutely sure that fonts are going to be used correctly, then you should fonts that are hosted remotely.

Comment: Agree for simple sites. But, for i18n / CJK this is a necessity. Font files are massive (2-3 MB *per weight*) so... 10 MB+. Hence, why i18n stacks rely on system fonts same as emoji stacks. For emojis.... Who cares? You don't have "font" considerations. It's just color and doesn't matter. For i18n... as you stated things get more difficult. In the latter case which can be buggy as described I'd question the mappings of weights, etc also. Theoretically, as you stated should be fine *if* the font system is robust which is a big if. Even subsetting external fonts is a no most of the time.

Comment: As a real concrete example via a quick search. A stack of locals for japanese is: `font-family : 'ヒラギノ角ゴ ProN' , 'Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN' , '游ゴシック' , '游ゴシック体' , YuGothic , 'Yu Gothic' , 'メイリオ' , Meiryo , 'ＭＳ ゴシック' , 'MS Gothic' , HiraKakuProN-W3 , 'TakaoExゴシック' , TakaoExGothic , 'MotoyaLCedar' , 'Droid Sans Japanese' , sans-serif;`

Comment: Yes, I hadn't considered emojis. To be honest, 10MB does not seem that large, especially considering the font will then be cached. Of course you may have a special circumstance where you need to be especially mindful of download size. Either way, it sounds like you're going to need to pick your poison: either fiddle with `font-synthesis` and put yourself at risk of the user's device not being configured correctly, or make your user eat the larger download size.

Comment: "To be honest, 10MB does not seem that large, especially considering the font will then be cached." Mate.... this is web dev.... Where we run things through stacks of automation / ops to shave off mere kilobytes and hope images are <10 KB with <1 second loads for lighthouse. 10 MB render blocking is effectively not having a site at all. Much less some visitors that's actually i18n with a 2/3G connection. But, yes I'd agree in the sense it's a poor decision either way.

Comment: Well yes, if your users are all on  2/3G mobile data connections then it's certainly an issue. That was not made clear in your post. To be clear, that's not just "web dev," that's a very specific kind of web dev. Are you using fonts that might be found on a popular CDN? If so, there's a decent chance that your users will have the fonts cached already.

Answer (score -2):

if you work with Visual studio you can just drag and drop it to css code page it will show you the font family name

Comment: This is not what was asked nor is it an answer. It's also based upon presumptions that don't hold relevancy.....

Comment: i can also see your name idk if i read it correctly , Monkey